# Objective-C string issue

Tags: objective-c, string

Hello I got an issue with this

```
for (NSString* fileName in fileList){
    if ( [fileName rangeOfString:@".png"].location != NSNotFound  ) {
        int x= col*130;



        NSLog(@"add %@", fileName);

        //create dynamically a nice thumbnail 
        UIImage* img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:
                        [self.documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName]
                        ];

        UIImageView* imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
        imgView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 110, 110);
        imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
        imgView.clipsToBounds = YES;

        UIButton* imgBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [imgBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(imgPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        imgBtn.frame = CGRectMake(x, row*130, 120, 120);
        //imgBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        [imgBtn addSubview:imgView];

        [self.canvas addSubview:imgBtn];

        [imgView release];


    col++;
        if (x > 760) {
            row++;
            col = 0;
        }
    }
```

this makes really nice thumbnail, but i want to make it with only files with specific name, so i have problem how to load only the specific name types. like e.g. I have images named ...city1,city2,city3, all are types png, and i also have car1,car2 .... also png. But once I want to load only cities and once only cars....

Is there any possibility to load only cities or only cars????

Thanks to all. 
I don't know how to make the exact comparison to string.

I would use something like this 
if(filename isequaltoString:@"car%")

but it doesn't work.. =(

Comment: This is not an xcode question, it's an objective-c question.

Comment: true:)don't you know how to get this to work??:(

Comment: Have a look at the NSString programming guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/SearchingStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000149-CJBBGBAI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have code to almost handle this...

```
 if ( [fileName rangeOfString:@".png"].location != NSNotFound  )
```

You just need to check for @"car" or whatever you are looking for, and you can't just check the location property or NSRange, because if you match at the first character index 0 your test above will fail.

> Return Value
>   An NSRange structure giving the location and length in the receiver of the first occurrence of aString. Returns {NSNotFound, 0} if aString is not found or is empty (@"").

You should check length as well.

Comment: and one little notice I can't check length because I can have 5é or hundreds of files like car in my documents directory. so I am unable to check lengthh of the string =) But thanks a lot =) Works perfectly:)

Comment: Not the length of the string, the length attribute of the NSRange.  This will tell you how many chars matched.

Answer (score 1):

this might work:

```
NSString *word = @"car1.png";
if ([word rangeOfString:@"car"].location == NSNotFound)
    NSLog(@"word does not contain car");
else
    NSLog(@"word contains car");
```

Comment: @rooftop `NSNotFound` is equal to `NSIntegerMax`, not 0, so the code will work.

Comment: bah, @Saphrosit you're correct, I misread {NSNotFound, 0} as NSNotFound == 0, instead of it being location, range. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

> I would use something like this if(filename isequaltoString:@"car%")

[isEqualToString:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/isEqualToString%3a)

Remember, documentation is **not** evil

However, in your case I'd rather use [hasPrefix:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/hasPrefix%3a)